# JSF correct way to update a value from a bean depending on validation

Tags: validation, jsf

I have a bucking bean associated to a page and I want to change its value depending on whether a validation failed or succeeded.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@ViewScoped()
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

String value="";
int number;

  /*getters-setters*/
}
```

a validator that checks if the number is positive

```
@FacesValidator("Validator")
public class NumValidator implements Validator{



    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        int num=(Integer)value;
        if(num<0){
            FacesMessage msg = 
                new FacesMessage(The number is negative");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
           }


    }
}
```

and a xhmtl page:

```
<h:form>
<h:inputText id="number" value="#{testBean.number}" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Is">
                    <f:validator validatorId="Validator" />
                    <f:ajax event="blur" render="msg" />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message id="msg" for="number"/>
</h:form>
```

And I want the String in the bean to be value="negative" or value="positive" whether the occastion. How can this be done?

Comment: What's the purpose of that value? Why would you ever have a model value which never hits the action method? Doesn't that value actually belong in the view side? By the way, you can also just use JSF's builtin `<f:validateLongRange>` validator if all you want is to validate if the value isn't negative.

Comment: @BalusC   I want to change the css of the input field whether it's true or not. So here's my logic. The css is connected to a string that is read from the xhtml. So that string should be changed accordingly, if the input is valid or invalid. Is my logic correct or should I go for javascript/jquery?

Comment: So, after filtering all the noise, your concrete question boils down to: "How do I change the style class of an input field depending on whether it has a validation error?", is that correct?

Comment: @BalusC yes, but I was more interested in what I was asking in case i need it somehow.

Comment: You shouldn't be asking [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The solution to problem Y is not necessarily the right solution to problem X. You should be asking about the concrete functional requirement instead of about a "possible solution" to the concrete functional requirement, which may be not the right solution after all.

Comment: @BalusC Ok i'll bear it in mind. Also I want to make a progress bar that is filled on how many inputs are correct, so somehow I should store the number of valid inputs. So can this be achieved with validators? And what about the css? Should I create another question?

Comment: I posted an answer. Remember that I've told you before to go get a sane book. Exactly for this reason. You're wildly poking around in the dark as to finding the "right solution". In future questions, try to ask about the concrete functional requirement alone. E.g. "*I have this code [...code...]. I would like to achieve [...behavior...]. How can I achieve this?"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concrete functional requirement appears to boil down to:

> *How do I change the style class of `<h:inputText>` when it has a validation error?*

In that case, just check [`UIInput#isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid()) in EL. The current UI component is just available by [implicit EL object](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects) `#{component}`.

```
<h:inputText ... styleClass="#{component.valid ? 'positive' : 'negative'}">
    <f:ajax ... render="@this msg" />
</h:inputText>
```

Note that I added `@this` to the `render`, otherwise the component itself wouldn't be updated.

You shouldn't be polluting the model with view-specific properties such as CSS classes. You should try to keep them in the view side as much as possible. This will end up in more "natural" solutions.

Comment: component.valid is a bound word or a variable from a bean name component? Also at bootstrap a to render a form input a <div> is required above the input field. So how can I change it's css?

Comment: As to first part, click the links (and read a book). As to second part, that's already answered in your previous question.

Comment: Its hard to find the books in my country,they are tοο specialized! Thx for your time and effort!

Comment: Is there any way so that initially I have a css class e.g. start and then change to two others classes of css(negative,poisitiv) regarding on validity of the input?

Comment: You could add a check on `#{facesContext.postback}`. E.g. `styleClass="#{facesContext.postback ? component.valid ? 'positive' : 'negative' : 'start'}"`.